# sybase boolean variable or workaround?

Tags: sybase

No bool (variable) in sybase I guess? Is there a workaround?

```
select @w=width, @h=height from Rectangles where id=1
select @a = @w * @h
select @isWide = @w > @h          -- doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way is to use sign function
Select @isWide = sign (@w - @h)

Or case statement
Case when @w > @h then 1 else 0 end

Can't check myself because I hav't sybase db now.